# Why is my game hero flying instead of jumping in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn how to develop a 2D game in Unity. I would like to make the hero jump and fall. However, my game hero is flying instead of jumping. When I press the related key, it jumps and never falls.

I'm probably making a logical mistake. I define a boolean which is called `checkJump`, but I am not sure whether it works. Once I press the related `X` key on the keyboard, I see the `Check Jump` option is enabled. However, it is never disabled again. In this reason, the game hero never falls down.

Here are the related variables:

```
[SerializeField]
private bool checkJump;
[SerializeField]
private float jumpForce;
```

Here is the `Jump()` function which is called in the `Update()`:

```
private void Jump () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.X)) 
        {
            checkJump = true;
            JoePlayer.velocity = new Vector2 (JoePlayer.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
           checkJump = false; //If I apply this, then the boolean never turns back to the enabled status.
    }
```

If I write the `checkJump = false` boolean to the out of the `if` block, then the boolean is never enabled, but the game character continues to fly. So the boolean which is in the if block never works.

[Click here for the display result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbF4R.gif)

How can I achieve to make the game hero jump and fall? The hero should jump and fall automatically when the player presses to the `X` key.

Comment: I call the `Jump()` function in the `Update()`.